# How do doctors learn to spot cancer in moles?

Tags: dermatology, cancer, moles

It is very clear to me that doctors do not use the [ABCDE rule](https://www.healthline.com/health/skin-cancer/abcd-rule-for-skin-cancer#how-its-used) to check a mole for skin cancer, as I probably have 30-40 moles that clearly violate one or more of these rules, yet the doctor always gives a cursory glance at them and says they're fine. If one is supposed to self check themselves monthly for skin cancer, how can they do it if this rule is meaningless (i.e. I can't go to the doctor every time a mole violates them because then I would always go)? Is there a textbook doctors learn to check from? Or are self-checks just to look for new or changing moles?

Comment: Why do you think a person who examines moles every day needs more than a quick glance? Even I can evaluate those criteria with little more than a quick look and I'm not a physician.

Comment: Well, either way, there's something else that's being evaluated because lot of things would violate those rules, but aren't actually a problem.

Comment: Doctors learn to identify suspicious lesions by looking at normal skin (and the freckles/moles on it) day after day after day after day after day. Plus, they look at a *lot* of pictures of skin cancer. I believe the most important thing is that a lesion with unnatural appearance of any kind arouses suspicion, which the doctor then acts upon.

Comment: When I was in private practice, yearly physicals were the norm. I was doing one on a 31 y.o. woman. I kept looking at her forearm skin, stretching it, puzzled. It just looked "off" somehow. "I don't like the look of your skin," I said. She answered, "You said that last year." Surprised, I said, "Then we'd better do something about it." With her permission, I did a punch biopsy. It came back as "diffuse squamous cell carcinoma in situ." A dermatologist treated it with two topical antineoplastic drugs. They had been all over her body. Being suspicious at the right time is a blessing.